# Problems with namespaces and require

Tags: clojure

I have a project created with `lein new app myapp`.

In my project, I've edited the generated `src/myapp/core.clj` file to:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:import myapp.example)
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  []
  (println (myapp.example/foo "bar")))
```

And have the file `example.clj` next to it, with:

```
(ns myapp.example)

(defn foo [x]
    (str "Hello, " x))
```

I've tried this in lots of permutations of `require`, `use`, etc, but every time I do `lein run`, I get:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapp.example`

`lein compile` has no output, so I assume it's successful.

What's the correct way to use function `foo` here?

Comment: `import` is for java namespaces. You want `(:require myapp.example)`

Comment: Just tried with `require`, now I get `Can't find 'myapp.core' as .class or .clj for lein run: please check the spelling`, followed by a `FileNotFoundException`, somehow.

Comment: Nevermind, small mistake in the second file.